# Changing order of one array with respect to another in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays `A` and `B` with one-to-one correspondence i.e. values corresponding to `[0,1] in A` is `10 in B`, `[0,2] in A` is `20 in B` and so on. Now I sort `A` to yield a new array `A1`. How do I generate `B1` with respect to `A1`? The desired output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 3],[2, 5],[3, 4],[3, 6],[4, 7],[5, 6],[6, 7]]])
B = np.array([[[10],[20],[30],[40],[50],[60],[70],[80],[90],[100]]])
A1=np.sort(A,axis=1)
#A1=array([[[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 3],[3,4],[2, 5],[3, 6],[5, 6],[4, 7],[6, 7]]])
```

The desired output is

```
B1=array([[[10],[20],[30],[40],[60],[50],[70],[90],[80],[100]]])
```

Comment: This is the same as your last question, just substitute `B` for `A` in the second line of the answer i.e. `np.array(B[0][order])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `argsort()` function and `[:]` operator to ahieve the desired result:

```
A = np.array([[[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 5],[3, 4],[4, 7],[5, 6]]])
order = A[0,:, 1].argsort()
A =np.array([B[0][order]])
print(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `argsort`:

import numpy as np

```
A = np.array([[[0, 1],[0, 2],[1, 3],[2, 3],[2, 5],[3, 4],[3, 6],[4, 7],[5, 6],[6, 7]]])
B = np.array([[[10],[20],[30],[40],[50],[60],[70],[80],[90],[100]]])
idxs = np.argsort(A, axis=1)

A1 = np.take_along_axis(A, idxs, axis=1)
B1 = np.take_along_axis(B, idxs, axis=1)
```